# Регулярные выражения в python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Господа, помогите плз.

Есть три ссылки

```
a = "realty.ru/offers/kvartiry
     avito.ru/uhta
     avito.ru/mowsow"

li2 = re.findall("\w+\.\w+/\w+", a)
print(li2)
```

При таком коде он ищет тока последние две сылки. Не получается сделать чтобы можно скока угодно групп он искал, пример слеш слово, слеш слово, слеш слово и так до бесконечности

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
li2 = re.findall("\w+\.\w+(?:/\w+)+", a)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает))